# Can I delete messages from the trash after x days in mutt?

Tags: mutt

I'd like to use a trash folder in `mutt`. I know how to create a macro that moves mail to the trash folder instead of deleting. However, I'd also like to automatically delete messages that sit there for seven days (as Thunderbird can do).

My mail is stored in `maildir` format. I could create a crontab that deleted files/messages from the trash directory, but it'd have to know when files were transferred. I thought a simple way might be to `touch` files as they were transferred. Then, I could just delete based on modification date. Is there a way to do make `mutt` touch files as it moves them, or is there a better way to delete files periodically from the trash?

Comment: The `ctime` would reflect that time. `gfind trash -ctime +7 -type f -delete`. In maildir, the `mtime` is meant to reflect the date of the email.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Oh brilliant. Thanks for that. Could you please make it an answer? I'll change the question to fit what I really wanted. (Also, out of interest, does a change in ctime mean mutt changed the file's inode too?)

Comment: If it just does a `rename()`, the content of the inode should not change (other than the `ctime`). The content of the directories (and therefore their `mtime`) will be updated obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if this can be done within mutt itself, but this can be achieved by a script in your (ana)crontab instead.

```
find /path/to/trash-maildir/cur -ctime +7 -type f -delete
```